# Exhaustively pattern match based only on the type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a sealed trio of case classes. Will Scala tell me if this match is exhaustive (I'm guessing not)?

```
value match {
  case a: A => methodThatNeedsA(a)
  case b: B => methodThatNeedsB(b)
  case c: C => methodThatNeedsC(c)
}
```

I could do the following, which I understand will be exhaustive - but since I don't need to decompose the expression, it looks very messy:

```
value match {
  case a @ A(_) => methodThatNeedsA(a)
  case b @ B(_, _) => methodThatNeedsB(b)
  case c @ C(_, _, _) => methodThatNeedsC(c)
}
```

Is there a better way to dispatch like this based purely on type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested your code with:

```
sealed trait Base
case class A(x: Int) extends Base
case class B(x: Int, y: Int) extends Base
case class C(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Base
```

If I remove any of the three `case`s in pattern matching:

```
value match {
    case a: A => methodThatNeedsA(a)
    case b: B => methodThatNeedsB(b)
    //case c: C => methodThatNeedsC(c)

}
```

The compiler issues warning:

```
warning: match is not exhaustive!
missing combination              C
```

Comment: Wow, ok - I just assumed it wouldn't be able to check because it involves dynamic casting! Silly assumption. Thanks!